# calling function for all elements in sequence one at a time xquery

Tags: function, for-loop, xquery, sequence

I am trying to call a function for every element in a sequence but I either get only one of the elements or all of them at the same time. 
My sequence has the form $y = ("N","K")and I want to run my function with first the letter N and then the letter K.
My code is:

```
for $nr in 1 to count($y)
let $n := ($y)[$nr]
return local:checking($n)
```

But that loop never ends... which I think is because the $n that i send to the function is both "N" and "K".

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks fine, though it could be simplified to `for $yy in $y return local:checking($yy)`. Whatever is wrong, it's not the code you have shown us.

Comment: With XQuery 3 you can also shorten that to `$y ! local:checking(.)`, see the simple `map` operator https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-map-operator.